# Does a free general purpose ASN.1 Decode/Dump/Inspect program exist?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, utility, asn.1

Does a free general purpose ASN.1 Decode/Dump/Inspect program exist?  I have a suspect ASN.1 block which may have failed decryption, and I would like to inspect it to see it it appears valid, and if so what elements it contains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also used `dumpasn1` with good success for a couple of years), then I decided that looking at 200-lines long nested tags was a bit difficult to follow onscreen and wanted something more dynamic, so that I could collapse parts of the tree and stuff like that.

That's what I'm trying to create with my very own [asn1js](http://lapo.it/asn1js/) client-side javascript ASN.1 decoder. It's also opensource and uses dumpasn1's huge "known OIDs" config file.
Doesn't try to detect all ASN.1 format errors, only the impossible-to-decode ones... (e.g. won't bother to differentiate DER from BER such as an INTEGER with extra leading zeros)

Yep, this is shameless self-promotion, but I hope you can find that software useful related to the problem you have in your question. ;-)

Comment: Your website is invaluable; I love it!

Answer (score 4):

My favorite tool for ASN.1 viewing is Peter Gutmann's [dumpasn1](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/dumpasn1.c). Command-line only, but very flexible and gives diagnostics in case of errors.

Answer (score 2):

This viewer utility is free, and seems quite good.

http://lipingshare.com/Asn1Editor/